# How to use different java version by alias?

Tags: java, bash, shell

I have some tools that can only be run by java 8. So i downloaded java 8,  but now i have two versions of java installed at the same time (os : Ubuntu):

```
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1101       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

**My question is:** is it possible to call these both versions by different aliases? For example i type:

- "java" to call java 11 (the default) and
- "java8" to call java 8

Comment: What does `type -a java` say? It's possible that you already have `java` that is a symlink to the specific java compiler.

Comment: It says `java is /usr/bin/java` which should default to 11?

Comment: And now `file /usr/bin/java`.

Comment: `/usr/bin/java: symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/java` which I guess is java11?

Comment: Oh, you probably have Debian-something. What does `java -version` say?

Comment: Yes I'm using Debian OpenJDK  it says `openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.2, mixed mode)
`

Comment: What is your host operating-system? Edit your Question with this info.

Comment: Unless you have to use them at the same time, you can check out [sdk man](https://sdkman.io/)

Answer (score 6):

You could do it in a couple of ways. The easiest way would be to put the following 2 lines in your profile initialization file:

```
alias java='/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'
alias java8='/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'
```

Other ways are depending on whether you are the admin of the machine or not. You can create soft links like this:
`/usr/bin/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64`
(Not recommended since certain tools in your system may depend on `/usr/bin/java`).

Update: Try to use [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/) if you can. Makes the job of installing java versions and setting up `JAVA_HOME` env variable simple.

Comment: would it not be better to have  java point to the "/usr/bin/java" ? It would avoid any confusion around system updates etc.

Comment: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64` is a directory I think I should add /bin/java

Comment: Sometimes you may face issues if you have other tools that you /usr/bin/java and expect it be certain version but you changed it to point to version 11 or something. Generally, it is not such a big problem but you may face some subtle issues.

Comment: Aliases aren't honored by scripts -- much better to use the Debian alternatives system to select the interpreter to use, since that'll work not just for direct invocations at a shell but for invocations *from* another program (like a build script or an IDE!) as well.

Comment: @VivekAkupatni Does aliases in profile also work in non-interactive mode, i.e. in scripts?

Comment: It won't work on non-interactive mode unless you do something. One way would  be to put the settings in a common bash script say like `common_utils.sh` and source the file in the beginning `source common_utils.sh`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as well for JAVA_HOME:

```
alias java8="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`"
alias java11="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11`"
```

Updated:
To run java directly use:

```
$ alias java8="`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`/bin/java"

$ alias java11="`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11`/bin/java"

$ java8 -version

java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)

$ java11 -version

openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

You can hardcode your path as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I have some tools that can only be run by java 8. So I downloaded java 8, but now I have two versions of java installed at the same time (os : Ubuntu).

You could do this using aliases (see other answers) but this has the problem that only a shell will respect an alias ... and then only if it has the alias defined or loaded by the shell:

- Aliases are not inherited via the environment.
- Whether a tool's launch script will see the aliases will typically depend on whether you put the alias definitions into the *correct* shell init file.
- It is also possible that an application's launch script will assume that `java8` or `java11` is a genuine (absolute or relative) pathname, and try to resolve it via the file system.

In short, there is a good chance that using an alias won't work in your use-case.

---

So a better idea is to arrange that the appropriate Java is on the Command Search Path.  You could do this a number of different ways:

1. You could use the Ubuntu "alternatives" system to **globally** switch between Java 8 and Java 11.
2. You could update the `PATH` variable so that (for example) the Java 11 executables come before the Java 8 executables.  This could be done in shell init files (per user or globally), in the application launch scripts ... or by hand.
3. You could even replace "/usr/bin/java" or whatever with a direct symlink to the version you want to use.  (This is crude, and I wouldn't recommend it.)  Note that the Java command entries in "/usr/bin" are probably already symlinks.)